# Calendario en android usando Date Picket

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Estoy tratando de agregar un calendario a mi aplicación, mi código es el siguiente:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    btn_fecha = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_fecha);
    btn_hora = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_hora);
    btn_next_fecha = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next_fecha);
    eFecha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eFecha);
    eHora = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eHora);
    btn_fecha.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_hora.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    btn_next_fecha = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next_fecha);

    btn_next_fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent btn_next_fecha = new Intent(SelectDayActivity.this, DatosAutoActivity.class);
            startActivity(btn_next_fecha);
        }
    });
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v==btn_fecha){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        ano = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                eFecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
            }
        }
        ,dia, mes, ano);
        datePickerDialog.show();


    }
```

Mi código funciona, sin embargo, cuando aparece el calendario muestra el año 1900 y me gustaría que apareciera la fecha de hoy (la fecha actual que tiene el celular)

Me podrían apoyar para hacer eso?
Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Agrega esta línea :

```
dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

debajo de:

```
@Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                eFecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
            }
        }
        ,dia, mes, ano);
----> Agregala aqui <-------
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Debo declarar la variable dpd?

Comment: Lo siento, tu variable tipo DatePicker es igual a dpd. (datePickerDialog = dpd) solo cambia, datePickerDialog por dpd y listo :D

Comment: Funcionó correctamente Javier :')